# Java texture loader says png is not supported but images display correctly anyway

Tags: java, png, textures

I'm having this strange issue. I just converted all of my images from gifs to pngs, and then changed the file extention that I'm looking for in my code to png, and now the console keeps being spammed with this:

> Sun Feb 22 23:39:37 CST 2015 WARN:class org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData >failed to read the data
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format for this image
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGDecoder.decode(PNGDecoder.java:272)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.PNGImageData.loadImage(PNGImageData.java:97)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:62)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.CompositeImageData.loadImage(CompositeImageData.java:43)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:292)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
>       at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:200)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
>     at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:340)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:349)
>     at helpers.Artist.ClearScreen(Artist.java:73)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:87)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)

The strange part is that the images are all being displayed correctly. I have NO idea why this is happening. Here's the code that's trying to load the images:

```
public static Texture LoadTexture(String path,  String fileType){
    Texture tex=null;
    InputStream in=ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try{
        tex =TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType,in);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tex;
}

public static Texture QuickLoad(String name){
    Texture tex=null;
    tex=LoadTexture("res/"+name+".png","PNG");
    return tex;
}
```

Does anyone have a clue to what's happening? I'll post more information if needed.

**UPDATE**

I changed the code, but it's gives me an error message, and then the program closes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
public static Texture LoadTexture(String path, String fileType){
    Texture texture=null;
    try{
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        texture = BufferedImageUtil.getTexture(fileType,bufferedImage);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return texture;
}

public static Texture QuickLoad(String name){
    Texture tex=null;
    tex=LoadTexture("res/"+name+".png","PNG");
    return tex;
}
```

And here's the error message

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:352)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:362)
>     at helpers.Artist.BeginSession(Artist.java:69)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:16)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:352)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:362)
>     at helpers.Artist.BeginSession(Artist.java:70)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:16)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:352)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:362)
>     at data.MenuSelection.(MenuSelection.java:11)
>     at data.Menu.createSelectionElements(Menu.java:80)
>     at data.Menu.createMenu(Menu.java:22)
>     at data.Menu.doMenuAction(Menu.java:283)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:81)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:352)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:362)
>     at data.MenuSelection.(MenuSelection.java:12)
>     at data.Menu.createSelectionElements(Menu.java:80)
>     at data.Menu.createMenu(Menu.java:22)
>     at data.Menu.doMenuAction(Menu.java:283)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:81)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>     at helpers.Artist.LoadTexture(Artist.java:352)
>     at helpers.Artist.QuickLoad(Artist.java:362)
>     at helpers.Artist.ClearScreen(Artist.java:75)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:87)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at helpers.Artist.ClearScreen(Artist.java:75)
>     at data.Boot.(Boot.java:87)
>     at data.Boot.main(Boot.java:155)

Comment: Only 2 things I can think to try. 1) Try resetting the path variables. 2) The image conversion you used was faulty. What software did you use to convert the Images? Maybe try another.

Comment: It seems that that PNG decoder does not support the full set of PNG formats, see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610295/slick-pngdecoder-error-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-unsupported-fo